# How can i convert a Png file to Gif in memory?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
if (Form1.sf != null)
            {
                radarDI = new DirectoryInfo(Form1.sf);
                radarFiles = radarDI.GetFiles("*.png");
                for (int i = radarFiles.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    radarImage = Image.FromFile(radarFiles[i].Name);
                    radarImage.Save(FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    myGifListRadar.Add(radarFiles[i].Name);
                    if (myGifListRadar.Count == 5)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                radar_animation.MakeGIF(myGifListRadar, @"d:\RadarGifAnimatoion.gif", 8, true);
            }
```

I want to convert all the png files to gif.
Since I need to create animated gif and it's getting only gif files.
So now im saving the png files to the hard disk make the convertion and then reading back the gif files from the hard disk:

```
radarImage.Save(FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

FileName should be later on the files im saving and then reading back to use it.
The question is if there is any way to convert the files to gif without saving it to the hard disk first ? Some quicker way then saving the files to the hard disk convert then read them again as gif's with FileInfo again ?

Just updated:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                if (Form1.sf != null)
                {
                    radarDI = new DirectoryInfo(Form1.sf);
                    radarFiles = radarDI.GetFiles("*.png");
                    for (int i = radarFiles.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        radarImage = Image.FromFile(radarFiles[i].FullName);
                        radarImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                        myGifListRadar.Add(radarFiles[i].Name);
                        if (myGifListRadar.Count == 5)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                radar_animation.MakeGIF(myGifListRadar, @"d:\RadarGifAnimatoion.gif", 8, true);
            }
```

But now this part:

```
radarImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                            myGifListRadar.Add(radarFiles[i].Name);
```

myGifListRadar is List how can I add now the radarImage to the List as string file name ?

Comment: And how much loss of quality I will lose when converting fron png to gif ?

Comment: Consider doing the conversion using a temporary file.  It will make debugging easier and you could save a significant amount of resources.

Comment: Sparksis temporary file do you mean by converting the png files to gif on the hard disk and then read back and use the gif files from the hard disk instead using the memory ? And resources do you mean by memory ?

Comment: @Jhonathan, I do indeed mean to use the HDD.  While write times are much slower it will still provide better resource usage from a general purpose POV.  If this is meant to be added to a web application it will increase scalability.  As you have not mentioned why doing this in memory is a necessity I'm just adding $0.02 that may or may not increase the overall value of the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Image.Save(Stream, ImageFormat)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx):

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream)
{
    radarImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    // do something with ms
}
```

Depending on how you are making a GIF with multiple frames, this might be unnecessary - can you just take the separate `Image`s and make the multi-frame GIF directly instead of making separate GIFs and then merging them?

Comment: Tim I don't have the gif animation class now since it was on c++ and I converted it to c# the important code I needed but I don't have the source now. So this line: radar_animation.MakeGIF(myGifListRadar, @"d:\RadarGifAnimatoion.gif", 8, true);
radar_animation is UnFreezWrapper class wich can get only List<string> myGifListRadar and can get only gif files. And on my hard disk I have only png files. And Unfreez is a free small program to create animated gif's and free one so used it's c++ source to convert it to c# but I don't have the c++ or c# source of the wrapper to change it.

Comment: My program is downloading each X seconds/minutes png files to the hard disk. I can save them to the hard disk directly as gif's but I think it will lose quality and im not sure if it will work in all my other program parts since I need the original png files in other parts of my program. So I prefer to make the convertion only in this part of my program.

Comment: Tim what other way I could make the convertion quicker ? Does it bad idea to use this stream memory convertion ?

Comment: From what you wrote, I think the only way to interface with this Unfreez app is to save the files on the hard drive first.  As Sparksis recommended, use temporary files (look up `%TEMP%`) to make sure you don't keep the files around indefinitely.

Comment: Your other obvious option: find a different library.

Comment: Tim ok I will use the hard disk option. Just wonder why using the MemoryStream is not a good idea ?

Comment: Using a `MemoryStream` is probably a good idea if `MakeGIF` can accept it in the parameters somehow.  However, it looks like your C# wrapper for the C++ code takes a `string[]` of file paths, thus you can't use `MemoryStream`s.